# jQuery countdown progress bar

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

is there a jquery plugin for progress bar that can count down to a specified date automatically.

I found some progress bars but none can do this automatically.

what I want to do is that the plugin calculate time remaining between two values and display the progress in a progress bar.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should a regular progressbar plugin + this [countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).

The code would be something like this:

```
$('#hidden').countdown({until: liftoffTime, format: 'HMS', onTick: updateProgressBar}); 

function updateProgressBar(periods) { 
        //update progress bar
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you won't have much luck with this, because this is a highly specialized requirement.

But you can easily code this yourself:

- Use a normal progressbar
- Set the progressbar minimum to `0` and the maximum value to the number of seconds between now and then.
- Use `setInterval` or the jQuery timer plugin to increment the progressbar every second.

Of course you can use any other interval, besides seconds.